# Reading from OpenCV FileStorage gives runtime crash

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to read some data from YAML file using OpenCV `FileStorage` class, but VS 2013 is giving a `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'fsi' was corrupted`.

```
FileStorage fsi(intrinsicsPath, FileStorage::READ);
    Mat M1, M2;
    if (!fsi.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Error1" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }       
    fsi["M1"] >> M1; fsi["M2"] >> M2;
    fsi.release();
```

This error doesn't occur in VS2012. I am using OpenCV 2.4.6

If I click "Abort" in the dialog, the program keeps going OK and it reads correctly the data from the file in question.

I would like to either find out what the problem is or disable the dialog, such that the program keeps going...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by upgrading OpenCV 2.4.6 to 2.4.9.